# Linux /var directory vs /opt directory

Tags: directory, installation, torque

From my limited experience in linux, I find a lot of 3rd party programs are installed by default to:

`/opt`

One program in particular, [torque](http://www.adaptivecomputing.com/support/download-center/torque-download/), installs by default to:

`/var/spool/torque`

I can override this with

```
./configure --with-server-home=/opt/torque
```

Is there any reason I should leave the default install directory alone, and not move it to

`opt/torque`?

I want someone who knows linux best practices to suggest where they think I should install it.

**Update**
I've researched File Hierarchy Standards (FHS). It seems like /opt and /var/opt are both valid locations for installing programs. I'd still like to know what is considered 'best practice' or even the most common location for installing applications.

Comment: Is its "server home" also the root of its installation? It may be two different things, even if one of them *defaults* to another during `configure` step (does it also accept `--prefix`?).

Comment: Yes, configure does accept a prefix. configure --prefix=/usr/local/ would put the bin and sbin directorys in the /usr/local/ directory.  If you leave off the --prefix, everything (binary, bin,sbin) are all placed in the home dir.

Comment: Then that `/var` thing is not the installation root, conceptually, it's probably some kind of a data directory. Original intent of having some data (like a webserver document root) in `/var` is to allow mounting `/usr` read-only. Do what you want and don't worry.

Comment: I can tell you that it won't hurt anything if you change the server home, many many sites do that for their torque installation. I know that some people fiercely oppose installing things to /opt, although I can't really articulate why (he said that it wasn't secure to modify the /opt directory).

Comment: I'm writing a chef script to install torque automatically. I am going to put it in /var/spool/torque even though this seems like a really weird place to put it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is more than one 'correct' place to install programs.

According to the [Filesystem Hierarchy Standards](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/), user programs are frequently installed to `/opt/` or `/usr/local`

While there is nothing wrong with /var/spool/torque as your install directory, it does not follow the FHS.

Answer (score 0):

This actually depends. If the program is a spooler then its installing in the correct location (that is var/spool). If not, then you should change it.

Also about opt vs var/opt generally in modern systems, the root directories (/run,/opt etc) and their "var" counterparts (/var/run,/var/opt) are treated as equal, and in many distros they are actually linked to one another.

So its pretty much your choise. Personally i choose to install under /var because many servers have it mounted on a different disk for data security and redundancy and i would like to make their life easier!